# Application Loader Warning - The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: setTags:

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript, air, adobe

I´m getting this warning when uploading any app build with Adobe Air to AppStore using Application Loader.

"The app references non-public selectors in Payload/.app/: setTags:"

This never happened before , but in the last two months everytime I try to upload an ipa built with Adobe Air happens. At the moment is not a big problem, Apple reviews the app and aproves it without problems , but this make me think at any time Apple would reject these Apps.

Thank´s for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this too. I thought it might be to do with certain ANE's being used.

Comment: Certainly I think it may be any problem with ANE´s, something has changed in Application Uploader, the problem is how to find out what I have to change. I hope can get a solution before Apple starts rejecting Apps with this warning :(

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I am using 3 ANEs: GoViral by MilkmanGames, Product Store and Game Center from the Adobe Gaming SDK.

It looks like the problem is coming from the Game Center ANE. I can't submit an update for my game when using Game Center.